# How would I effectively convert a string into a slug using Apex?

Tags: apex

I am looking to quickly and efficently convert a string like `Digital Marketing` to a slug like `digital-marketing`. How would I achieve this in Apex. I could break the string into two parts but I am looking for something better.

Comment: Define 'better'....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a toLowerCase and replaceAll. This will convert to lower case, then remove special characters, then replace white space with hyphens.

```
String value = 'Digital Marketing';
String slug = value.toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll('[^a-z0-9\\s]+', '').replaceAll('[\\s]+', '-');
```

Comment: @Ali Gajani just in case you are looking to replace only the first occurrence of the white space use replaceFirst instead of replaceall

Comment: I would also add a `.removeStart('-').removeEnd('-')` just to be safe regarding special characters and numbers at the beginning and end of the string. If one inserted a smiley face (`:)`)  at the end, for example, the slug would end with a hyphen. Aesthetically speaking the dangling hyphen can bother some people.